# Trigram index for ILIKE patterns not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.2, performance, pattern-matching, postgresql-performance

I've got a simple but slow query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title  
FROM ja_jobs
WHERE title ILIKE '%RYAN WER%'
AND clientid = 31239
AND time_job > 1457826264
ORDER BY title
LIMIT 10;
```

**Explain analyze:**

```
Limit  (cost=5946.40..5946.41 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=2746.759..2746.772 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Unique  (cost=5946.40..5946.41 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=2746.753..2746.763 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=5946.40..5946.41 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=2746.750..2746.754 rows=4 loops=1)
              Sort Key: "title"
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "ja_jobs"  (cost=49.02..5946.39 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=576.275..2746.609 rows=4 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (("clientid" = 31239) AND ("time_job" > 1457826264))
                    Filter: (("title")::"text" ~~* '%RYAN WER%'::"text")
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 791
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "ix_jobs_client_times"  (cost=0.00..49.02 rows=1546 width=0) (actual time=100.870..100.870 rows=795 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (("clientid" = 31239) AND ("time_job" > 1457826264))
Total runtime: 2746.879 ms
```

Then, I created a trigram index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_ja_jobs_trgm_gin ON public.ja_jobs USING gin (title gin_trgm_ops);
```

**Explain analyze after adding the index:** (Yes, I `analyze`)

```
Limit  (cost=389.91..389.91 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=3720.511..3720.511 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Unique  (cost=389.91..389.91 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=3720.507..3720.507 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=389.91..389.91 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=3720.505..3720.505 rows=0 loops=1)
              Sort Key: "title"
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "ja_jobs"  (cost=385.88..389.90 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=3720.497..3720.497 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (("clientid" = 31239) AND ("time_job" > 1457826264) AND (("title")::"text" ~~ '%RYAN WER%'::"text"))
                    Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 4
                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=385.88..385.88 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=3720.469..3720.469 rows=0 loops=1)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "ix_jobs_client_times"  (cost=0.00..50.00 rows=1644 width=0) (actual time=0.142..0.142 rows=795 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (("clientid" = 31239) AND ("time_job" > 1457826264))
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "ix_ja_jobs_trgm_gin"  (cost=0.00..335.63 rows=484 width=0) (actual time=3720.213..3720.213 rows=32 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (("title")::"text" ~~ '%RYAN WER%'::"text")
Total runtime: 3720.653 ms
```

As you can see, the index did not work.

Table `public.ja_jobs`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.ja_jobs (
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT "nextval"('"ja_jobs_id_seq"'::"regclass"),
  refnum character varying(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  clientid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  customerid bigint,
  time_job bigint,
  priority smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  status character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active'::"bpchar",
  title character varying(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,

  -- some other irrelevant columns
)
```

Indexes on `public.ja_jobs`:

```
Indexes:
    "ja_jobs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, "btree" ("id")
    "ix_bill_customer_jobs" "btree" ("customerid", "bill_customer")
    "ix_clientid_jobs" "btree" ("clientid")
    "ix_customerid_job" "btree" ("customerid")
    "ix_ja_jobs_clientid_modified_date_created_date" "btree" ("clientid", "modified_date", "created_date")
    "ix_ja_jobs_gsdi_pk" "btree" (("id"::"text"))
    "ix_ja_jobs_trgm_gin" "gin" ("title" "gin_trgm_ops")
    "ix_job_customer_recent_jobs_lookaside_bill_customer" "btree" ("bill_customer", "modified_date")
    "ix_job_customer_recent_jobs_lookaside_clientid" "btree" ("clientid", "modified_date")
    "ix_job_customer_recent_jobs_lookaside_customer" "btree" ("customerid", "modified_date")
    "ix_jobs_charges_and_parts_sort" "btree" (("charges_count" + "parts_count"))
    "ix_jobs_client_times" "btree" ("clientid", "time_job", "time_arrival")
    "ix_jobs_fts_description_en" "gin" ("full_text_universal_cast"("description"))
    "ix_jobs_fts_full_address_en" "gin" ((((("full_text_universal_cast"("address"::"text") || "full_text_universal_cast"("suburb"::"text")) || "full_text_universal_cast"("city"::"text")) || "full_text_universal_cast"("stpr"::"text")) || "full_text_universal_cast"("postc
ode"::"text")))
    "ix_jobs_fts_job_number_en" "gin" ("full_text_universal_cast"("job_number"::"text"))
    "ix_jobs_fts_refnum_en" "gin" ("full_text_universal_cast"("refnum"::"text"))
    "ix_jobs_fts_title_en" "gin" ("full_text_universal_cast"("title"::"text"))
    "ix_jobs_full_address_street_first" "btree" (((((COALESCE("address"::character varying, ''::character varying)::"text" || COALESCE(' '::"text" || "suburb"::"text", ''::"text")) || COALESCE(' '::"text" || "city"::"text", ''::"text")) || COALESCE(' '::"text" || "postc
ode"::"text", ''::"text")) || COALESCE(' '::"text" || "stpr"::"text", ''::"text")))
    "ix_jobs_paying_customers" "btree" ((COALESCE("bill_customer", "customerid")))
    "ix_jobs_status_label_ids" "btree" ("status_label_id")
    "ix_jobs_top_by_client" "btree" ("id", "clientid")
    "ix_mobiuser_jobs" "btree" ("accepted_mobile_user")
    "ix_recurrenceid_jobs" "btree" ("recurrenceid")
    "ix_timejob_jobs" "btree" ("time_job")
    "ja_jobs_client_type" "btree" ("clientid", "jobtype")
    "ja_jobs_the_geom_idx" "gist" ("the_geom")
```

#### Question:

What can I do to improve the query? Why is the trigram index not working as expected?

**UPDATE:** Re-ran the explain analyze buffer

```
Limit  (cost=199669.37..199669.39 rows=10 width=20) (actual time=31523.690..31523.691 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=26947 read=101574 dirtied=438
  ->  Sort  (cost=199669.37..199669.40 rows=11 width=20) (actual time=31523.686..31523.686 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: "title"
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        Buffers: shared hit=26947 read=101574 dirtied=438
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "ja_jobs"  (cost=4850.60..199669.18 rows=11 width=20) (actual time=11714.504..31523.640 rows=1 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (("clientid" = 2565) AND ("time_job" > 1382496599))
              Filter: (("title")::"text" ~~* '%Hislop%'::"text")
              Rows Removed by Filter: 207654
              Buffers: shared hit=26942 read=101574 dirtied=438
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "ix_jobs_client_times"  (cost=0.00..4850.60 rows=155054 width=0) (actual time=11670.956..11670.956 rows=215142 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (("clientid" = 2565) AND ("time_job" > 1382496599))
                    Buffers: shared hit=121 read=5772
Total runtime: 31524.874 ms
```

After removing `DISTINCT` and the left `%`:

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
SELECT title  
FROM ja_jobs
WHERE title ILIKE 'Hislop 13035%'
AND clientid = 2565
AND time_job > 1382496599
ORDER BY title
LIMIT 10;


Limit  (cost=2275.53..2275.55 rows=9 width=20) (actual time=3492.479..3492.483 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=4940 read=448
  I/O Timings: read=83.285
  ->  Sort  (cost=2275.53..2275.55 rows=9 width=20) (actual time=3492.475..3492.477 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: "title"
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        Buffers: shared hit=4940 read=448
        I/O Timings: read=83.285
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "ja_jobs"  (cost=391.62..2275.38 rows=9 width=20) (actual time=3492.460..3492.462 rows=1 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (("title")::"text" ~~* 'Hislop Street Clinic 2513035%'::"text")
              Filter: (("time_job" > 1382496599) AND ("clientid" = 2565))
              Buffers: shared hit=4940 read=448
              I/O Timings: read=83.285
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "ix_jobs_trgm_gin"  (cost=0.00..391.62 rows=482 width=0) (actual time=3492.427..3492.427 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (("title")::"text" ~~* 'Hislop 13035%'::"text")
                    Buffers: shared hit=4939 read=448
                    I/O Timings: read=83.285
Total runtime: 3492.531 ms
```

- As you can see, the query is hitting the new index but it's slower.

Then I removed `ORDER BY` but the query is still slow.

Also, I tried to use `LIKE` (with is much faster), but `LIKE` is case-sensitive, so for that reason I got no rows back. Can't use it.

Comment: Sorry @ErwinBrandstetter - Question updated. We'll be migrating to Postgres 9.5.. but it'll take a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of indexes. I doubt you need all of them. Check whether all of them are in use. Instructions in the manual, chapter [Examining Index Usage](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-examine.html).

If your system is [configured to gather statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-INDEXES-VIEW), it will be particularly revealing to study:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_indexes
```

These statistics are also displayed in pgAdmin.

Some indexes are particularly odd, like: `"ix_ja_jobs_gsdi_pk" "btree" (("id"::"text"))` - why would anyone cast a `bigint` id to `text` for indexing?

Useless indexes are not going to impair read performance (much), but they are a burden on write performance and general maintenance.

---

The **major difficulty** for your query is to **estimate the selectivity** of your various predicates. That's comparatively simple for the `bigint` columns `clientid` and `time_job`, but *hard* for pattern matching (`title ILIKE 'Hislop 13035%'`).

In your case (UPDATE 3), Postgres estimates to find 482 rows matching the pattern, but it turns out to be just a single row:

> Bitmap Index Scan on "ix_jobs_trgm_gin" (cost=0.00..391.62 **rows=482** width=0) (actual time=3492.427..3492.427 **rows=1** loops=1)

Tuning the query depends on the complete picture: Cardinalities, data distribution, hardware, load, concurrency, query frequencies, priorities ...

It *may* help to increase the statistics target for involved columns:

```
ALTER ja_jobs
   ALTER clientid SET STATISTICS 1000
 , ALTER time_job SET STATISTICS 1000
 , ALTER title    SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

Then: `ANALYZE ja_jobs;` But don't expect much. Details:

- [Check statistics targets in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034896/939860)

Estimating selectivity of free-floating `LIKE` patterns is *hard*. Left-anchored is easier - you are mixing these two rather different cases freely: `ILIKE '%RYAN WER%'` (with leading wildcard) is much more complex than `ILIKE 'Hislop 13035%'`. Overview:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

There have been improvements for the latest version, but the biggest improvements come with Postgres **9.6**  and its new version of the pg_trgm module. [Consider the release notes here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/release-9-6.html#AEN137326) Related:

- [Trigram search gets much slower as search string gets longer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111523/trigram-search-gets-much-slower-as-search-string-gets-longer/111579#111579)

There are various other ways to improve performance, depending on all the information that's not in your question. Maybe a multicolumn index, or a partial index or a CTE in your query.

All the general advice for performance tuning applies as well:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)
- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization

You already removed the expensive `DISTINCT`. If you don't need `ORDER BY title`, it may change the query plan completely to drop that, too: With both of these removed, Postgres is free to pick the first 10 matches and ignore the rest. Else, *all* matches have to be found and considered. can be ***much*** more expensive. Try:

```
SELECT title
FROM   ja_jobs
WHERE  title ILIKE 'Hislop 13035%'
AND    clientid = 2565
AND    time_job > 1382496599
LIMIT  10;  -- no ORDER BY
```

---

If you actually only deal with **left-anchored `LIKE`** pattern (trailing wildcards like `'Hislop 13035%'`, but not: `'%RYAN WER%'`), then you can use a very fast `varchar_pattern_ops` index. Detailed explanation:

- [Operator "~<~" uses varchar_pattern_ops index while normal ORDER BY clause doesn't?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/operator-uses-varchar-pattern-ops-index-while-normal-order-by-clause-doesn)

So:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_ja_jobs_special_idx ON public.ja_jobs
(clientid, title varchar_pattern_ops, time_job);
```

Index columns in *this* order. Equality first, range later. Explanation:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/multicolumn-index-and-performance/33220#33220)

You can extend this solution to cover `ILIKE` with a functional element

```
CREATE INDEX ix_ja_jobs_special_idx ON public.ja_jobs
(clientid, lower(title) varchar_pattern_ops, time_job);
```

And adapt your query:

```
SELECT title
FROM   ja_jobs
WHERE  lower(title) LIKE lower('Hislop 13035%')
AND    clientid = 2565
AND    time_job > 1382496599
LIMIT  10;
```

- [Index on column with data type citext not used](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105244/index-on-column-with-data-type-citext-not-used/105250#105250)

Answer (score 0):

The two analyses differ in the text comparison, the first shows `~~*`, i.e. case insensitive (ILIKE) whilst the second shows only `~~`, i.e. case sensitive (check if you didn't run LIKE by mistake the second time).

Comment: not sure.. I've re-ran the query anyway. Please check my updated question and the `UPDATE 2` field please.